# Global variables in Python 3 class

Tags: class, python-3.x, initialization, global-variables

How to use a global variable inside the initialiser of a class in Python 3?

for eg

```
import urllib
from urllib.request import urlopen
class ABC(object):
 def __init__(self):
   x=urlopen('http://www.google.com/').read()
```

How do I convert x into a global variable?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to declare your variable before the class declaration and use the global statement on the init function:

```
import urllib
from urllib.request import urlopen

x = None

class ABC(object):

 def __init__(self):
   global x
   x=urlopen('http://www.google.com/').read()
```

Comment: if I print x it says None. However I wanted it to return the source code.

Comment: sorry for that, you have to declare global inside the init function and not on the class declaration! I edited the answer, it works now!